# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I use ASP.NET MVC3 .NET4 Framework. My project is working on local but I send files to server and is doesn't work there. 
In my server file is v2 now. If i send v2 file to server i get

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=1.0.0.0,...

error

Comment: Are you deploying using FTP or the VS Publish functionality?

Comment: I use FTP.
I changed all dll files and then web.config file. It's work now.

Comment: [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000506/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages-razor-version-2-0-0-0

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET MVC 4, the namespace is not System.Web.WebPages.Razor, but System.Web.Razor
That worked for me, change your web.config.

still not resolved then Verified that .csproj file contains for ALL referenced assemblies, so it will always take it from Bin folder, instead of GAC.

Comment: There is also a System.WebPages.Razor namespace, used internally