# WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was getting this error which is not allowing me load my website. I'm new to .net and can some guide me on this?

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.

> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   Microsoft.Web.Helpers.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization
>   method Start on type Microsoft.Web.Helpers.PreApplicationStartCode
>   threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1
>   methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +874
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
>   methods) +169
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +133
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +176
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +734
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization
>   method Start on type Microsoft.Web.Helpers.PreApplicationStartCode
>   threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +112    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +716
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1073.0

I don't find the solutions in the previous posts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000506/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages-razor-version-2-0-0-0)

Comment: @Hackerman I don't the reasonable answer in that duplicated question.

Comment: In my question I don't have any version in web.config file

Comment: Yeah but you also have `Microsoft.Web.Helpers` wich depends on `System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0`

Comment: I tried in that way but it doesn't solved my issue